# When did Chris stuff his ear with cotton?

Tags: plot-explanation, get-out

I find it significant that they did not show Chris stuffing his ears with cotton (to stop from being hypnotized) during the end of *Get Out* because, given his situation, it was impossible. Can someone explain how this this was achieved?

Comment: I just know that he was pulling cotton out of the arm of the chair. That's where the cotton came from. But I think you're saying that the way he was tied up, he couldn't have reached up to his ears with his hands...?

Comment: That's right. It's a problem

Comment: That's why they included the scene of him trying to untie his wrist restraints with his teeth. If he could lean down far enough to bite the restraints, he could lean down far enough to put cotton in his ears.

Comment: @user56reinstatemonica8 - cotton in your teeth does not help you get cotton into your ears, without use of your hands.

Comment: Eh? Who said anything about cotton in his teeth?  The point is, there was a scene where he moved his head down into a position where we can see that he was capable of reaching his ears with his fingers. It's a nice little way of showing how he could do it, without spoiling the reveal by showing him doing it; for the benefit of people watching for a second time or thinking back over what happened.

Answer (score 10):

> If the mountain will not come to the prophet, then the prophet must go to the mountain.

He does not need to move his arm up to put the cotton in his ear, because he can simply put his head down to his hands. 
It is clearly visible that his upper body is not constraint.